# Synology disconnects router periodically

Tags: networking, nas, synology

I have the following home network:

- Synology DS411+ (DSM 5.2)
- Cisco DCP3825 router
- Linksys WRT54GS running in gateway mode

Ever since I installed the DS unit on the network, I've been experiencing intermittent network failures from the unit itself and on other laptops. These failures last ~30secs and occur seemingly randomly every few minutes. Here are some observations of the failure:

- web browsers on local Linux laptops show "resolving host..." and fail to access sites
- accessing the router via the browser or pinging it does not respond
- torrents on the Synology unit are disconnected
- other local machines are still accessible, including the Synology unit
- accessing the Synology unit via my external IP no longer works
- Android / iOS devices are not affected by the failure

When I disconnect the DS unit from the network, these problems disappear. I've tried disabling a number of services from the unit without success:

- Windows sharing
- IPv6
- HTTPS

One additional observation that may be related is that running the "External Access > Router Configuration" setup shows me that the unit detects TWO routers, not just one, even though my WRT54GS is in gateway mode.

[image]

I need help to diagnose this problem and resolve it. Thanks!

Comment: it sounds like your DNS is being interrupted. What devices do you have DHCP servers on, and do any of your devices point to the NAS for dns lookup?

Comment: The only enabled DHCP server is on the router. The one on the NAS is disabled. The NAS has a static IP address, pointing to the router as gateway. On my Ubuntu laptop, `/etc/resolv.conf` has `nameserver 127.0.1.1` and `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` has `supersede domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4;`

Comment: I've also changed the WRT config to "router" with no change in behaviour.

Comment: Disabling the WRT completely also did not modify the behaviour, or the report above.

Answer (score 0):

> accessing the Synology unit via my external IP no longer works

This is your problem. For ease of use the DS units(and some others) use UPnP to try and intercept WAN traffic so that you can remotely access them. This isnt really the right way to do things, it should be statically assigned an address and the required ports forwarded, but thats not home user friendly.

1. Disable remote access features("cloud") on Synology, reboot it, test to ensure stable
2. Manually configure remote access features and use port forwards to allow access. Ideally you should NOT use port 80/443.

NB: Your DCP3825 may also be a lot more stable if you add a small fan to it like its sister model the 3925, one of the components loves to overheat.

Source: Working L1 for a large ISP.

Comment: Thanks. I am already running with QuickConnect disabled (if that's what you mean by "cloud") and port forwarding done manually on the router. 

I have added info describing an additional gateway device in the network that may play a role in the problem.

Comment: Regarding the fan: the previous owner had installed an additional one.